# vaule wont go any higher in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so in my database i store my users earnings but they will not go any higher than 0.99999 i try and add 0.000001 to it but will not go over to 1.00000 for some reason the column is decimal(5,5)

here is my update

```
  $fdfsdfdsfsdf = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET available_earning=available_earning+0.00012 WHERE id  = '".$owner2."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

what am i doing wrong? Sorry about my variable names and yes i will be updating it all to pdo soon

Comment: Try setting decimal to `decimal(65, 30)` and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Please consider using `mysqli` instead of `mysql`. `mysql` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the column as `DECIMAL (5, 5)`. That means 5 significant digits, with *all five* to the *right* of the decimal point. The term "significant digits" means *all* digits on *both sides* of the decimal point.

Short version: you need to redefine the column as `DECIMAL (x, 5)` where `x > 5` if you want to store values >= 1.